# Unity: Rotating The Camera Using The Law Of Cosine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, euler-angles, trigonometry

I am making the basic controls for a game that is mouse-oriented. I want the camera to follow the player and rotate around the player using the law of cosine to find an angle. Here is my code:

```
//Move Camera
camX = player.transform.position.x;
camY = 15.5f;
camZ = player.transform.position.z;

//Rotate Camera
rotTriA = player.transform.position.x;
rotTriB = player.transform.position.z;
rotTriC = Mathf.Sqrt((rotTriA * rotTriA) + (rotTriB + rotTriB));

if(rotTriA > 0 && rotTriB > 0)
{
    getAngle = (Mathf.Acos(((rotTriA * rotTriA)
        + (rotTriB * rotTriB)
        - (rotTriC * rotTriC))
        / (2 * (rotTriA) * (rotTriB))) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
}
else if(rotTriA > 0 && rotTriB < 0)
{
    getAngle = (Mathf.Acos(((rotTriA * rotTriA)
        + (rotTriB * rotTriB)
        - (rotTriC * rotTriC))
        / (2 * (rotTriA) * (rotTriB))) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) + 90;
}
else if(rotTriA < 0 && rotTriB < 0)
{
    getAngle = (Mathf.Acos(((rotTriA * rotTriA)
        + (rotTriB * rotTriB)
        - (rotTriC * rotTriC))
        / (2 * (rotTriA) * (rotTriB))) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) + 180;
}
else if(rotTriA < 0 && rotTriB > 0)
{
    getAngle = (Mathf.Acos(((rotTriA * rotTriA)
        + (rotTriB * rotTriB)
        - (rotTriC * rotTriC))
        / (2 * (rotTriA) * (rotTriB))) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) + 270;
}
else if(rotTriA == 0 && rotTriB > 0)
{
    getAngle = 90;
}
else if(rotTriA == 0 && rotTriB < 0)
{
    getAngle = 270;
}
else if(rotTriA > 0 && rotTriB == 0)
{
    getAngle = 0;
}
else if(rotTriA < 0 && rotTriB == 0)
{
    getAngle = 180;    
}
else
{
    getAngle = 0;
}

Debug.Log(getAngle);

if (camZ < 0)
{
    camZ = player.transform.position.z + 10.5f;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(135f, getAngle, 0.0f);
}
else
{
    camZ = player.transform.position.z - 10.5f;
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(45f, getAngle, 0.0f);
}
camZ = player.transform.position.z - 15.5f;
cam = new Vector3(-camX, camY, camZ);
mainCamera.transform.position = cam;
```

I know how to make the camera follow the player, but I don't know how to make the camera rotate around the player without it freaking out.

Possible reasons why this is occurring: I am using raycasting to move the player, so when I move my mouse outside of the arena, the movements wont register, I might not be doing the law of cosine right because I get values up to 400 (which shouldn't be possible, given a circle is 360 degrees).

Comment: Are you doing this just for the sake of doing it?  Because if you're just looking for an easy way to have a camera rotate around an object it can be done with some addition and basic Unity APIs

Comment: @Foggzie I couldn't think of an easier way of doing it.

Comment: @Foggzie I just want it to rotate around the player.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make a camera rotate around the player would be to take advantage of the game object heirarchy.

First make an empty `GameObject` and then make your camera a child of it:

```
EmptyObject
  > Camera
```

Now orient your camera to look at the position of the empty object.  The location of this empty object is now where your camera is "Looking".  Since the camera is a child, if you rotate this object, the camera rotates around it (while maintaining the orientation of facing the empty object).

A simple script to rotate the empty object will, thanks to transform parenting, make the camera "orbit" around it while looking at it:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float rotationAcceleration; // radians/(frame^2)
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSpeedMax; // radians/frame
    [SerializeField] private float rotationDamping; // 0.99

    private float rotationSpeed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rotationSpeed = rotationSpeedMax / 4;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rotationSpeed += rotationAcceleration;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rotationSpeed -= rotationAcceleration;
        }

        rotationSpeed = Mathf.Clamp(
            rotationSpeed, -rotationSpeedMax, rotationSpeedMax);

        transform.Rotate(0f, rotationSpeed, 0f);

        rotationSpeed *= rotationDamping;
    }
}
```

Attaching something like this to the `EmptyObject` object will do the trick.  Now you just need this empty object to follow your character. The rotational functions accept radians as arguments so you'll want to use small [0.00 ~ 0.01] numbers. Also, this is a per-frame implementation so it'll only work smoothly while your frame rate is smooth; you'd want to eventually have `Time.deltaTime` factor into it.

Comment: I want the camera to rotate based off of where the mouse is from the center.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko You're gonna need a drawing or some visual to explain it; I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @BradleyWilliamElko Although the script and logic is easily portable; it solved the challenge of getting a camera to rotate around any given object, you can change the input to accept whatever you'd like.